# Should fork be first synced with master or should you commit changes first?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-fork

I am working on a repository and forked it 2 days ago. After forking and cloning it in my local, I made changes over these past 2 days. I have not yet committed any changes nor I have pushed my feature branch to my fork. Meanwhile in these 2 days, the original repo got ahead of my forked repo by some n commits.
So now should I commit my changes and push my feature branch to my fork first or should I first sync/update my fork with original repo?

Comment: in the end you'll have to solve the same conflicts either way.

Comment: As @Piglet said, but I find it better to sync the local branch with original before pushing.